# What causes align to object to fail so incredibly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, creative-cloud

<sup>(Ai 2014 CC)</sup>

Edit: Specifically this is when copying and pasting from one file to another file.

I'm using align to "Key Object" not align to "Artboard"

**What I find odd is that it moves more every time I press allign.**

Has anyone else experienced this and have an explinanation as to why this happens?

An obvious solution is to manually move the object but I'd rather have an explanation, not a solution.

Although, a solution would be appreciated if offered.

NOTE: I've censored the actual art but you can still see it's bounding box and a rough idea of the elements inside. Both of these objects are independently grouped, so I'm not selecting the wrong key object.

ALSO NOTE: **In the gif I never deselect anything.**

[image]

Comment: Do you have Align to Artboard or Align to Selection checked? Looks like you have some sort of offset applied, but I've never seen that before.

Comment: @ckpepper02 I'm using align to Key Object not align to Artboard

Comment: Why the close vote? How does this not have to do with graphic design? I'm sure everyone here uses align to object every single day. I'm sure this would be helpful to multiple people.

Comment: So is the object you are aligning with have it's center point in the correct location? Grasping at straws here.

Comment: @ckpepper02 I never changed it's center point. It's artwork I'm pasting from a different job that I didn't create.

Comment: To align to a key object first select all objects, then with the black pointer click on the key object. This will turn on the feature and highlight the selection of the key object with a blue line to indicate this. You don't have to use the pull-down menu. If you use the pull -down menu without first clicking with the selection tool on one of the selected objects Illustrator will align to one of the selected objects that is on top of the stack.

Comment: Found that from here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1088777 Just FYI in case there is a step you may have missed.

Comment: @ckpepper02 Both objects are grouped so that is an impossible mistake to make in this particular scenario.

Comment: @ckpepper02 also that doesn't explain why it moves each time you press it. It should never move again after aligning it. Once it's aligned to center, it's in the center so there's nowhere else for it go.

Comment: This happened to me a number of times while opening artwork from other providers or via EPS or SVG or PDF or even older AI formats. I did not find a solution and always assumed this is a bug. Possibly rogue or hidden objects affecting the way align behaves.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64704/adobe-illustrator-strange-behavior-while-aligning-objects -- (note also references CC2014, might be a clue) I, personally, have never seen this behavior. And the duplicate, while it has a few answers, none are up voted or marked correct. It **must** be something with the file itself and the object construction. My sheer and utter *guess* would be possibly symbol registration points????

Comment: I think no one will find the solution without having that file. you could send it and the issue will be solved, probrably.

Comment: I get this quite often with objects that come from non-Illustrator PDFs. Sometimes copy/pasting into a fresh AI file remedies the problem, but not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Partial answer

Saving before using align, then opening the file, does seem to fix it.

My hunch is it has something to do with a partially deleted object and a clipping mask because if one of those elements are missing then this doesn't happen.

[image]

Comment: Ah so information is cached somehow.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not sure I follow. If that's your explanation as to why it only works when you don't save I'd be curious if you have a slightly more detailed guess ;)

Comment: @joojaa I'd be happy to share the actual file with you. It's confirmed to work with Ai 2014 - Ai 2017

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, usually when I have an issue like this in illustrator (and I have the time) I'll dupe the file and delete assets one at a time and see if that resolves the issue. Sometimes I start with broader strokes (delete whole groups, etc).

I wonder if this could have anything to do with how the assets are grouped?

Also, when you align to selection or artboard does it behave normally?

Answer (score 0):

Object > Flatten Transparency > Move Raster slider to 100 > Check Convert all text to outlines just in case.  Then try to align.