# Aligning objects in Illustrator does not produce expected result

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, layout

I believe I am an expert **Illustrator** user, but I've never seen this weird behavior before.

The **Align** setting is set to "**Align to Selection**". However when I click "**Horizontal Align**" or "**Vertical Align**", the objects move *away* from each other. Each subsequent click on the **Align** Panel moves them further away from each other.

[image]

I tried resetting **Bounding Boxes** in the **Transform** panel, which proved fruitless.

### Am I doing something wrong, or is this the latest Illustrator glitch?

<sub>Illustrator 23.0.4</sub>

Comment: Seen it only once or twice.. copy/paste to a new file generally clears it.. whatever it is.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64704/adobe-illustrator-strange-behavior-while-aligning-objects

Comment: Okay, then closed as duplicate of previous question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this strange behaviour with aligning or distributing stuff. Noticed it generally happens when importing third party artwork, icons especially downloaded from this or that website in SVG.

These are done is who knows what AI version (possibly even done via Inkscape) and sometimes i think there's some 'junk' info or leftover points that can affect how alignment works. Sometimes found one single dot waaaaaaay outside the artboard that was affecting this. Things like that.

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and take a look at the bounding box, as it may include stuff outside/far from your actual objects.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, as I worked with these components before (and they are all from AI files), but Scott's comment fixed it